# How to combine all related dictionaries in a python list

Tags: python

I have a source list as below:

my_list = [{"values":[289],"key":52},{"values":[319],"key":52},{"values":[46,863,319,803,138,107,832,169],"key":52},{"values":[111],"key":11}]

I need to convert this as:

my_list = [{key:52,values:[289,319,46,863,319,803,138,107,832,169]},{key:11,values:[111]}]

I am new to python programming and not able to figure out how can I achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Solved it using collections.

Comment: from collections import defaultdict

my_list = [{"values":[289],"key":52},{"values":[319],"key":52},{"values":[46,863,319,803,138,107,832,169],"key":52},{"values":[111],"key":11}]

tmp = defaultdict(list)

for item in my_list:
    tmp[item['key']].extend(item['values'])

parsed_list = [{'key':k, 'values':v} for k,v in tmp.items()]
print(parsed_list)